# Write a query to find the film which grossed the highest revenue for the video renting organisation

Tags: sql, database

select title from film where film_id in ("highest revenue")

select film_id from inventory where inventory_id in (
select inventory_id from rental group by inventory_id
order by count(inventory_id) desc ))

limit (highest revenue);

where im wrong?

Comment: Thats a bad question. No information, no tables given. You just posted your answer. Try adding more information about the table structure and its data.

Comment: @shubhangi my answer below was based on the syntax. Should you need a better answer, please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT title
FROM film
WHERE film_id in (SELECT film_id
FROM inventory
WHERE inventory_id in (
SELECT inventory_id
FROM rental
GROUP BY inventory_id
ORDER BY count(inventory_id) DESC
        )) limit 1;
```

even this code with joins will work

```
select Title
from film
inner join inventory
using (film_id)
inner join rental
using (inventory_id)
inner join payment
using (rental_id)
group by title
order by sum(amount) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: the second one is more accurate because it calculating the highest revenue generated film. First one calculating only the highest view.

Comment: The 2nd query is the only query that should give the right answer. because the first query depends upon no. of occurrences of a certain inventory, which should not give the proper answer. Let me know your thoughts

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT title
FROM film
WHERE film_id IN ("highest revenue")

SELECT film_id
FROM inventory
WHERE inventory_id IN (
        SELECT inventory_id
        FROM rental
        GROUP BY inventory_id
        ORDER BY count(inventory_id) DESC
        ) limit(highest revenue);
```

**Remove the ) after DESC**

Answer (score -1):

**Write a query to find the film which grossed the highest revenue for the video renting organization.**

```
select TITLE from FILM f 
inner join INVENTORY i using (FILM_ID)
inner join RENTAL r using (INVENTORY_ID)
inner join PAYMENT p using (RENTAL_ID)
group by TITLE
order by sum(AMOUNT) desc
limit 1;
```